# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: BottomSheetFragment{fc9d1db} (f54104c4-f862-420b-b30a-3fbd835554cf)}

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottom-sheet

I have added BottomSheetDialogFragment in my project. Here is the sample code below for a better understanding.

```
public class StickerBSFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

private ArrayList<String> arrayStickers;
private RecyclerView rvEmoji;

public StickerBSFragment() {
}

private StickerListener mStickerListener;

public void setStickerListener(StickerListener stickerListener) {
    mStickerListener = stickerListener;
}

public interface StickerListener {
    void onStickerClick(String sticker);
}

private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
            dismissAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
    }
};

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@Override
public void setupDialog(@NonNull Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
    View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_sticker_dialog, null);
    dialog.setContentView(contentView);
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();

    if (behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
        ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).addBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
    }
    ((View) contentView.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    rvEmoji = contentView.findViewById(R.id.rvEmoji);

    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 4);
    rvEmoji.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    loadRowData();
}

private void loadRowData() {
    arrayStickers = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayStickers.clear();
    try {
        arrayStickers.addAll(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getContext().getAssets().list("joker"))));
        rvEmoji.setAdapter(new LabelAdapter(getContext(), "joker/", arrayStickers));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class LabelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LabelAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> listImages;
    private Context context;
    private String folderName;

    public LabelAdapter(Context context, String folderName, ArrayList<String> listImages) {
        this.listImages = listImages;
        this.context = context;
        this.folderName = folderName;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_emoji_sticker, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Glide.with(context).asBitmap()
                .load("file:///android_asset/" + folderName + listImages.get(position))
                .fitCenter().skipMemoryCache(false)
                .into(holder.imgSticker);

        holder.imgSticker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mStickerListener.onStickerClick(folderName + listImages.get(position));
                dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != listImages ? listImages.size() : 0);
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgSticker;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgSticker = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgSticker);
        }
    }
}
```

And the code for showing the fragment.

```
StickerBSFragment mStickerBSFragment = new StickerBSFragment();
mStickerBSFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), mStickerBSFragment.getTag());
```

This code crashes in some devices randomly. I have tried to find out the solution but no hint regarding this issue. Error log generated by Splunk Mint library.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: StickerBSFragment{fc9d1db} (f54104c4-f862-420b-b30a-3fbd835554cf)}
1   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.addFragment(FragmentStore.java:67)
2   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1563)
3   at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:405)
4   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2167)
5   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1990)
6   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1945)
7   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1847)
8   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
9   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
10  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
12  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7191)
13  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
14  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:499)
15  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
```

What is wrong with this code? Please update for the same and please help out to resolve this issue.

Comment: if(mFragment.isAdded())
{
     return; //or return false/true, based on where you are calling from
} is this you want?

Comment: Post whole body of a function that creates this fragment and attempts to display it. I guess it is called through `mStickerListener.onStickerClick`.

Comment: @notTdar : I am not adding a fragment anywhere. So How I can check its added or not?

Comment: @AnandSavjani if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("someTag") == null && noTAdded...) 
    mStickerBSFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "someTag");

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu : I have added that code in the above post.  mStickerListener.onStickerClick is just to get item clicked of recyclerview. mStickerBSFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), mStickerBSFragment.getTag()); calling on button  click listener.

Comment: @notTdar : its not working in this case

Answer (score 0):

First create only one instance of the fragment then

```
mStickerBSFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
```

then call show

```
mStickerBSFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), mStickerBSFragment.getTag());
```